# How to set different SSRS Chart legend text colors

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want the text color of the legend items for a chart to be different colors based on an expression at runtime. Is this possible?

The "Color" property of the legend object is default "Black" - changing this will change ALL legend items. I want to change EACH differently. I've tried looking for access to intrinsic objects for SSRS but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot make a Chart's Legend change the color of the text for each value.

If you want to do a little extra work, you could make a separate legend out of a table which you would be able to color the text. Just use the same dataset and Group By the  Category Group that you are using in the chart. The downside is that you would need to set the colors for both the chart and table/legend manually.